# Shibboleth - multiple customers for one Service Provider

Tags: saml, shibboleth

I have installed Shibboleth as a Service Provider on one of my servers.  We provider software as a service to universities.  What I'm wondering is, what's the best way to handle multiple customers with a single Service Provider instance?

I came across this:

https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/EDS10/1.+Overview

But I don't want to display a list of schools that are in our network to students.  Is there a way to configure Shibboleth to automatically know who the customer is via the XML configuration rather than using the Embedded Discovery Service?

Answer (score 1):

The only way of doing that is to have a sub-domain for each of your customers. None of other methods will guarantee that you know which customer's IdP to use to login your users.

`customer1.yourservice.com`, `customer2.yourservice.com` etc shouldn't be a big deal to configure on DNS level. But you have to keep in mind SSL certificates.

Comment: This is definitely how I plan to do it.  I'm just trying to now understand how to set up the SP shibboleth.xml file.